# pip install multiple users on shared server

Tags: python, pip

At work we have a Windows machine with a lot of power. It runs different programs, software etc., but as a Python user I would also like to be able to run scripts, write code etc. on that machine as well to take advantage of the power.

As of now we have gotten Python installed. The issue arises when I log onto the server with my account, then when I do a e.g. `pip install numpy` it installs this package on my account/user folder. So basically that means that every person logging in needs to download every package from the beginning if they want to use it etc. Somewhat not what we want to do.

So my question is: How do we enable global installation from all users via pip ?

Comment: [how-to-install-program-to-all-user-accounts-in-windows](https://superuser.com/questions/855360/how-to-install-program-to-all-user-accounts-in-windows)

Comment: I did ``pip install ....(your module)... --user`` and it works for us in our shared computer with multiple users.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe install python to the machine instead of installing it for a specific user?
In "Customize installation->Next":
Select `install for all users` when installing python.

Create a public package installation folder, like `"C:\Users\Public\site-packages"`
Add or set `public installation folder` to environment variable `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONUSERBASE`
Execute `pip config set global.target [YOUR PUBLIC FOLDER]` in command line.
Then pip will install package to the public folder and also python could find it by `PYTHONPATH` and `PYTHONUSERBASE`.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This has been done. One administrator installed it so every account can use Python as they want. The problem is when each user is using `pip`. THEN it will install as it was per user instead of globally.

Comment: Set the PYTHONUSERBASE environment variable to a public folder to change the package installation location may work. I need sometime to test it.